# How to detect User scroll event in google maps V2 for Android

Tags: android, events, scroll, google-maps-android-api-2

My application has separate algorithms to fetch data for scroll change and on user location change . For location change am using `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener`      Which is working fine.

But for on user scroll, I am getting  `mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener()`. But the issue is **com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListene** also triggers  **mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener()**.

So how to distinguish. Presently I am using Boolean values to differentiate, but it's not reliable and dirty.

Comment: What's your current algorithm?

Comment: It can be like on user scroll will bring full screen bound data and on User location change will bring only new location bound change data. This just a scenario, the algorithm has many tasks. So need distinguish scroll and user location change

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt that there's an easy, reliable, and real-time way to do this. IOW, I suspect that it is going to be "dirty".

If I had to try, I would supply my own `LocationSource`, so that I knew when the map would be changing based upon position. I would then try to ignore the next call (calls?) to my `OnCameraChangeListener`, as being ones tied to the location change.

(BTW, note that `LocationListener` was deprecated)

Or, I would try to change my data-fetching algorithm to treat all camera changes equally. After all, if my objective is to make sure that I have data on all sides of the map from the current center, it doesn't matter *how* I got to that center, just so long as I am there.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue, was trying all sorts of stuff like wrapping the view to intercept touches, or wrapping any calls to change the viewport and listening to when it started and stopped changing so I could tell if something else changed it, or matching the current viewport to what I last set it to... it's all rather fiddly. Then someone pointed me at this, and it <s>looks promising</s> **update: has now worked flawlessly for us for months without a single issue**:

```
map.setOnCameraMoveStartedListener { reasonCode ->
    if (reasonCode == GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener.REASON_GESTURE) {
        // I will no longer keep updating the camera location because
        // the user interacted with it. This is my field I check before
        // snapping the camera location to the latest value.
        tracking = false
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why this isn't selected as the right answer. Works as expected.

Comment: Yeah I said at the time it looks promising but can now say we're using it on multiple screens of a very map-based app, for months, without a single issue. Works perfectly. Glad it helped! :D

Comment: I agree, this should definitely be the correct answer